# CSS center row of images on window resize

Tags: html, css, image, center

Hi I'm trying to create an image gallery that centers rows of images with fixed dimensions. The issue is the number of images in each row will change depending on the window size so I can't use mutiple containers and `margin: auto` them. Here is an example page that does what I'm after:
http://inspire-gwen.tumblr.com/
You'll notice that as you change the size of the window, the image rows change, but each one is still centered on the page. Is it possible to implement this with purely CSS? This is the code I have written, with some random images:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<body>
    <div class="img_container">
        <div><img src="http://www.tolooeyaran.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/City-Of-Paris-France-Tour-Eiffel-640x360.jpg"></div>
        <div><img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-h0DGPrWkU-M/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAABJY/0l_GW_IzQk4/photo.jpg"></div>
        <div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ElxvqJK.jpg"></div>
        <div><img src="http://i-cdn.phonearena.com/images/articles/168223-image/First-HTC-One-M9-wallpaper.jpg"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
.img_container img { 
    max-height: 300px;
    display: block;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

.img_container div {
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Images are by default inline items, wrapping them in 'div' tags is currently causing them to be block items. You could get by with simpler with this:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<body>
    <div class="img_container">
        <img src="http://www.tolooeyaran.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/City-Of-Paris-France-Tour-Eiffel-640x360.jpg">
        <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-h0DGPrWkU-M/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAABJY/0l_GW_IzQk4/photo.jpg">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/ElxvqJK.jpg">
        <img src="http://i-cdn.phonearena.com/images/articles/168223-image/First-HTC-One-M9-wallpaper.jpg">
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
.img_container {
    text-align: center;
}
.img_container img { 
    max-height: 300px;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is very possible..

so far you have been using `px` to define the image width... what you need is `%`.

Here is the JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/uh1wvaev/2/

Here is my code:

HTML

```
<div class="img_container">
    <div class="img_wrapper">
        <img src="http://www.tolooeyaran.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/City-Of-Paris-France-Tour-Eiffel-640x360.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="img_wrapper">
        <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-h0DGPrWkU-M/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAABJY/0l_GW_IzQk4/photo.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="img_wrapper">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/ElxvqJK.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="img_wrapper">
        <img src="http://i-cdn.phonearena.com/images/articles/168223-image/First-HTC-One-M9-wallpaper.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.img_wrapper {
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
}
img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

What I did was, I gave each `<DIV></DIV>` a class of `"img_wrapper"`. Then I gave each `img_wrapper` a width of 25% of the page. Therefore whenever the page is resized, the img will be given a width of 25% of the new window size.

### If you have any questions, or need further assistance please leave a comment below